# Android nested ViewModel with navigation controller

Tags: android, mvvm, nested, navigation, viewmodel

I have an activity with a fragment inside (**ParentFragment**).

The **ParentFragment** has a fragment with its navigation controller with multiple fragments.

The **ParentFragment's** ViewModel has title, subtitle and color properties.

Every time I navigate to another fragment the **ParentFragment's** ViewModel data should be updated (the fragments are the ones with the data), how can I achieve that?

I know how to share a viewModel, It doesn't fit the project needs, each fragment should have its viewModel, and the same for the **ParentFragment**.

```
class ParentFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var parentViewModel: ParentViewModel
}

class ChildFragment: Fragment() {
    private lateinit var childViewModel: ChildViewModel
}

class ParentViewModel : ViewModel() {
     var title: String? = null
     var subtitle: String? = null
     var color: Int? = null
}

class ChildViewModel : ViewModel() {
    init {
        // I need to access ParentViewModel and update title, subtitle and color here.
    }
}
```

Comment: @a_local_nobody source ?

Comment: that doesn't mean that a fragment can't contain another fragment

Comment: @a_local_nobody "Two Fragments should never communicate directly." is different from "a fragment shouldn't contain another fragment" which is false. Anyway imagine you have an Activity with a custom header shared for all fragments, and each fragment has the value to the header's text, that header's text will be part of the activity ViewModel, and if you don't want a huge ViewModel you will have one ViewModel per fragment not one shared between fragments and activity. The fragment shouldn't know about the activitie's ViewModel, that's why nested ViewModel is one solution, I just don't know how.

Comment: you are saying that, you have an activity, with a fragment, and all other fragments need to know the value of that other fragment ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I'm not saying that at all, in the hypothetical case I told you that the fragments update the activity header, the don't know about each other, and they don't know about the activity, but they have the activity header's text (like when you have a toolbar in the activity but the fragments are the ones with the info needed for the title).

Comment: I can't think of any situation where you'd need what you're describing @JSB, i hope you find what you're looking for :D

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement **ParentViewModel** in **ChildViewModel**

```
class ChildViewModel : ParentViewModel() {
    init {
        title = "Title"
        subtitle = "Sub Title"
        color = -123454
        // I need to access ParentViewModel and update title, subtitle and color here.
    }
}
```